# In DB2, how can I disable NLJOIN?

Tags: optimization, db2, join, execution-plan

I want to indicate to the optimizer, via SET or optimization profiles, that NLJOIN shouldn't be used at all when optimizing a query.

I've been looking for this for a while without any success. I looked for a property that could be set through the `db2set` command, but the only one referring NLJ is `DB2_INLIST_TO_NLJN`.

The closest I've found is through the usage of optimization profiles but those are very specific and what I need is a general setting that would apply to any statement being optimized.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to prevent nested loop joins?  *Especially* in a general sense (it sounds like you want to disable it for every query, not just one specific query) ?

Answer (score 2):

You might wish to check out [this article on join methods](http://etutorials.org/Misc/advanced+dba+certification+guide+and+reference/Chapter+6.+The+DB2+Optimizer/Joining+in+DB2+UDB/) and how DB2 chooses which one when.

Based on this documentation (which is for DB2 8 and I'm assuming it is similar for 9+, though not necessarily), nested loop joins are always available to the optimizer to use. DB2 can select merge sort and hash as the optimizer level is upped from 1 and other things are present (read the article to see which).

Answer (score 1):

Him

You can change the optimization class, in order to have the possibility to chose a merge scan or hash join instead of nested loop. However, the optimizer will decide which method is the best.

The second option is to use a profile for the optimizer: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0024530.html